# Editable sequence in WPF

Tags: wpf, controls, sequence

I need a control that allows a sequence of controls to be edited. Each control has a single associated value and the value of an editable sequence would be the sequence of those values. Editing the sequence refers to adding new elements, deleting existing elements and reordering elements.

I've written an editable sequence control that displays a dock panel with a list box, up and down arrows and a text box. Entering text into the text box and pressing return adds a new element with that name. Pressing the up or down arrows moves the currently selected element. Pressing DELETE when an element is selected removes it.

I'd like to examine other options. Do any built-in WPF controls provide this functionality? How might I compose existing controls to create what I need? Are there commercial solutions that would make my life easier?

**EDIT**: For example, it would be more user friendly to allow elements to be reordered using drag-and-drop. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: What *else* makes you unhappy about your existing solution? If it's only drag-and-drop that shouldn't be particularly difficult to implement.

Comment: @CosminPrund If I were to implement drag-and-drop then I'd want to drag an existing element and drop it either before, between or after the current elements rather than onto a current element. How do you do that?

Comment: @JonHarrop post your current code and XAML. also post a screenshot of what you need. I'm sure there's a much happier way to do it using the default WPF controls and proper `DataTemplate`s.